# Why does terraform aws code fail to render?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, terraform, render

Terraform version = 0.12

```
resource "aws_instance" "bespin-ec2-web" {
  ami = "ami-0bea7fd38fabe821a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.bespin-sg.id]
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.bespin-subnet-public-a.id
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  tags = {
    Name = "bespin-ec2-web-a"
  }
  user_data = data.template_file.user_data.rendered
}

data "template_file" "user_data" {
template = file("${path.module}/userdata.sh")
}
```

userdata.sh file

```
 #!/bin/bash
   USERS="bespin"
   GROUP="bespin"
   for i in $USERS; do
   /usr/sbin/adduser ${i};
   /bin/echo ${i}:${i}1! | chpasswd;
   done

   cp -a /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config_old
   sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/#PasswordAuthentication no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   sed -i 's/#PasswordAuthentication yes/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   systemctl restart sshd
```

**terraform plan result**

```
Error: failed to render : <template_file>:5,24-25: Unknown variable; There is no variable named "i"., and 2 other di
agnostic(s)

  on instance.tf line 13, in data "template_file" "user_data":
  13: data "template_file" "user_data" {
```

Why am I getting an error?

Comment: try double $ in your userdata.sh: `$${i}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `template` argument in the `template_file` data source is processed as Terraform template syntax.

In this syntax, using `${...}` has a special meaning, that the `...` part will be injected by some var that is passed into the template.

Bash also allows this syntax, for getting the values of variables as you're intending to use it.

To reconcile this, you'll need to escape the `$` character so that the terraform template compiler will leave it be, which you can do by doubling up the character: `$${i}` in all cases.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#string-templates

Comment: If you use $$ then the shell can only be run in terraform environment. I recommend to use `eval "$"{i}` which keeps shell as shell and works with terraform. I am wondering if there is an option to tell terraform not to interpret shell script.